# How can I write a function in Haskell that prints out every element of a tuple of any size?

Tags: list, haskell, tuples

I know I can do something like

```
listy = zip [1,2,3] [a,b,c]
testy = listy !! 0        --(1,"a")
let (x,y) = testy
putStr((show x) ++ " " ++ y ++ "\n")
```

to get 1 a

However, lets say I have a bunch of tuples like

```
("John","Cena")
("Chicken","Egg","Parmesan","Cream","Noodles","Milk")
("Beans","Rice","Meat")
("Tomato","Basil","IceCream","Midi")
```

How can I write a function that will work for any length of tuples and print them out like I did above?

Comment: Since all the "elements" of your tuples are of the same type in the latter examples, I strongly recommend using lists instead of tuples. Lists are much more regular than tuples -- and so admit much more regular programs for producing and consuming them.

Comment: Looks like [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to **print** every element of a tuple, tuple types have `Show` instances that will do that<sup>1</sup>, so `print` will print out every element of a tuple. It will however do so in Haskell syntax:

```
λ print (1, "foo", 2, "bar")
(1,"foo",2,"bar")
```

If you just want to *see* what values are in the tuples, then I suggest you simply get used to this format (rather than the space-separated no-quotes format your example seems to suggest). Nothing is going to be anywhere as close to as easy as just `print` or `show`.

The problem is that tuple types are not really *collections* the way that lists are.<sup>2</sup>

In a list, all of the elements are of the same type so it is easy to map a function over them (if a given function can handle any element of the list it can handle all of them). And lists of different lengths (but the same element type) are all members of the same type, so one function can handle lists of any length (to combine the elements into a single result, like your space-separated string).

In a tuple, however, the types of all of the items are independent. If I have a generic unknown tuple `(a, b, c, d ...)` then there is no possible function that I can map over all of the elements, because any function I might want to use will handle a **specific** type, and the tuple elements could all be **different** types. So there's no easy way to convert all of the elements of an unknown tuple to strings, for example.

This issue already came up in your own original example with printing tuples like `(1, "a")`. You had to say `show x` to get the first field converted to a string, but then just used `y` to "process" the second field; you used **different** code to handle each field, so you didn't in fact even *want* to do "the same thing" to all of them, even in just this tiny example.

Furthermore, tuples of different lengths are also different types and these types have no useful relation to each other, so they can't all be handled by the same function. Even if we assume we can convert all of the tuple elements to `String`, a function that accepts a 2-tuple of strings and combines its results would have type `(String, String) -> String`, while one that accepts a 3-tuple would have type `(String, String, String) -> String`, and so on. There's no way to unify all of these function types into a single `{{some-kind-of-tuple}} -> String` type that could handle any tuple. With no way to even express that type, there's no way we could write a function that could do that.

Really, the various tuple types `(a, b)`, `(a, b, c)`, `(a, b, c, d)`, etc are not actually related to each other, and should not be thought of together as "collections" in the way that lists, arrays, sets, etc are. A tuple is more like an "anonymous data type"; tuple syntax is just special shorthand syntax so we don't have to define things like:

```
data TwoItems a b = TwoItems a b
data ThreeItems a b c = ThreeItems a b c
data ElevenItems a b c d e f g h i j k = ElevenItems a b c d e f g h i j k
<etc>
```

If we did define those manually, each of those would be a separate data type, with no way to handle a `ThreeItems` with the same function that handles an `ElevenItems`. Nor would there be any automatic way to apply a function to every element of an `ElevenItems`; the things inside it are **fields of a data type**, not elements of a collection.

Tuples are **exactly** like that. We just have special syntax to make it easier to use these "boring" data types that do nothing but contain some number of fields of any independent types.

If we declared a bunch of separate data types and wanted to be able to turn any of them into a string, we would need to make a separate function for each type saying how to do it for that type; there's no way to write a single function that handles any of those data types.

We *can* use a type class to sort-of "merge" all of those separate functions into a thing that can be given a single name, but this works exactly the same as it would for making type class instances for any other type; it doesn't exploit any commonality between the different tuple types (because there isn't any). You still need to *write* all of the separate functions in the form of an `instance` declaration for each type. For converting things to strings this has already been done for you in the form of the `Show` class and instances, but if you don't like the format it uses that won't help you; you'll need to handle all of those tuple types separately, and then optionally use a type class to unify the definitions.

But really, the very fact that you want a program that has some unknown number of values and want to "the same thing" to all of them *almost always* indicates that the type you should be using to store them is a list (or other collection type), not a tuple. The change you should *actually* be making to your code is much more likely to be "don't store these values in fields of a tuple in the first place" rather than "write a bunch of separate functions for printing tuples of separate lengths".

---

<sup>1</sup> Technically only up to size 15. Tuples bigger than that are rather rare, however.

---

<sup>2</sup> If you're familiar with Python, you may be used to thinking of tuples as very similar to lists; if so I suggest making a conscious effort to train yourself out of this in Haskell, as it uses the distinction between lists and tuples for **extremely** different purposes than Python uses the distinction between the types it calls lists and tuples.

Comment: Nit: "no possible function that I can map over all of the elements". Of course there are loads of such functions. Any function that's parametric in its parameter would work: `id`, `const 5`, `\x -> (1, x)`, and so on.

Comment: @amalloy Absolutely true, though such functions inherently don't "do anything" with their parameter; they either return it unchanged, or return an unrelated value, or add some unrelated structure around the value. So they can't really "process" the values in the tuple (I know I'm not defining this very well, but anything useful for converting the fields to a common type that could be processed in a list-like fashion isn't parametric like this). I'll think about if I can reword that paragraph to respect the nit without just being needlessly confusing...

Answer (score 0):

You can't, every different length tuple is a different type, but Haskell is strongly typed, so a function can only accept arguments of a single type.

All your examples should be lists instead.